# How do I format a (W,H,3) numpy array for Android's Bitmap?

Tags: python, java, android, numpy, kotlin

In my python server program I do some image processing and end up with a (W,H,3) numpy array representing the raw RGB values of an image. The goal is to send that over to a client Android application.

This client application is then expected to read in the array of bytes, convert them to a bitmap, and ultimately display it in a normal ImageView.

I know you convert a ByteArray to a Bitmap via:

val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)

But how should I arrange my numpy array when i convert it to a linear array of bytes?

Comment: You seem to use three bytes per pixel and ARGB_8888 is four. So make it four before or use _### becoming three bytes.

Comment: `I know you convert a ByteArray to a Bitmap via:` Not always as a byte array can contain a jpg or png file too.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was obvious so I didn't mention it, my main point is I don't know how I should be formatting the numpy image array as a linear byte array

Comment: I dont know python but take the first row and put it in a byte array. Then take the next row and add it to it..

Comment: You dont have to construct a byte array first. You could just send the rows one by one. All depends on how that python array is organised.

Comment: You can also send all pixels one by one i think. And you should know how Android expects that byte array to be organized. Now do you?

Comment: I don't know what Android expects the byte array to look like, it's why i wrote the question. I couldn't find anything online or in the documentation either

Comment: I dont know either but then if you can find nothing know that you have to experiment with all the functions mentioned in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap or google examples for them and you will discover i hope..